# Powerpuff Girls Supervillain School

Tags: episode-identification, powerpuff-girls

I recall seeing a Powerpuff Girls episode with a super-villain school. In one scene a teacher was next to a blackboard, and on the blackboard were the syllables "Mwa-ha-ha-ha". The students were reading this aloud in the most mechanical, non-super-villain-laugh manner possible.

Any idea which episode this would be? I suspect Mojo Jojo was the teacher, but I'm really not clear on that.

Comment: OMG, never saw, but that sounds *hilarious*!

Comment: What series? There’s the original, the anime, and the reboot.

Answer (score 1):

If it was the original show, it appears to be Mo Linguish, because that is the only episode in which Mojo Jojo acted as a teacher.

He was sentenced to community service and made to teach citizens better English.

You can watch the full episode [here](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x6gzu1k).

See if it rings any bells. All in all, we still need more details. When did you watch it? What was the style, was it cartoon style or anime style?

Comment: "Mo Linguish" does not feature the scene describe by the OP.

Comment: I watched that episode (and several more), and now wonder whether it might have been Dexter's Laboratory . It certainly was cartoon-style (not anime), and completely silly (not like Akira or Ghost, etc)